# Crystal reports suppressed section still leaves blank spot

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Section that only contains a SubReport.

I have a formula on "suppress (no drill down)" that hides the subreport. This works.
However it leaves a big blank white space where the subreport would have been if it was visible.

I have ticked "Suppress Blank Section" and unticked "Keep Together" on the surrounding sections without any effect.  How do I change it so my hidden/suppressed section does not display any empty white-space?

I am using Crystal Reports 11.

**UPDATE** It may not be the blank sections causing the issue, could it be the 2nd sub report which I do want to show is 2 big to fit on the first page so just starts on the 2nd page.  I have unticked "New Page Before" and "Keep Togeather" for it

Comment: Do you have "Suppress Blank Section" checked on your SubReport as well?

Comment: Yes - but there is actually data for the sub report, but I just want to hide it based on a parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I sorted it out.

The problem was the next subreport / section I wanted to show was too long to fit on the first page so was starting on a new page each time.

To fix I had to right click the subreport click "format subreport" then click the subreport tab, then untick  "Keep Object Togeather"

Comment: Thanx 4 da solution.I was trying 2 do this for a whole day :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have suppress blank section in the sub report as well. Try checking this suppress blank section in all the sections of the subreport. It should work for you

Comment: I did not have that, I just tried clicking every suppress blank section in the sub report, but it did not help. Would I need to add the formula I have for supress - no drill down to every section?

Answer (score 0):

Use same or similar formula (which you use for subreport hiding) for main report section supressing too. "Supress blank section" doesn't work well with subreports.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the subreport. Format Subreport -> Subreport -> Suppress Blank Subreport.

This option is available at least on version 11.5.x