# crystal reports blank space issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crystal reports suppressed section still leaves blank spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974589/crystal-reports-suppressed-section-still-leaves-blank-spot)

I have created a sub report with in the main report footer section.my issue is when the main report page is not completely filled with data it gives a blank space between the main and sub report and the sub report starts with the next page.how can i remove this space?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a checkbox in the properties of the subreport for "Suppress if blank" or something similar.